# multimap of multimap not inserting data

Tags: c++, string, file, multimap

I am trying to read a file and put values in a multimap of multimap.
Insertion doesn't throw any errors, but when I try to print the values, the output is not not as expected.

**My input file:**

> Server1, Database, MySQL, 5.5
>   Server2, Database, MySQL, 5.1
>   Server2, OS, Ubuntu, 12.04
>   Server3, Language, Python, 2.6.3

I want to store the values like this:

> MySQL,5.5,Server1
>   MySQL,5.1,Server2

**My code:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef multimap<string,string> innermap;

multimap<string,innermap> mp;

void print()
{
    multimap<string, innermap >::iterator it;
    multimap<string, string>::iterator inner_it;

    for ( it=mp.begin() ; it != mp.end(); it++ ) 
    {
        cout<<(*it).first<<endl;
        for( inner_it=(*it).second.begin(); inner_it != (*it).second.end(); inner_it++)
            cout << (*inner_it).first<<"  " << (*inner_it).second << endl;
    }
}
int main() 
{
    string str_temp;
    vector<string>str;

    std::ifstream infile("abc.txt");

    while ( getline (infile,str_temp) )
    {
       int i=0;

       stringstream ss(str_temp);
       char delim=',';
       string server;
       string software;
       string version;
       string item;

       while (getline(ss,item,delim))
       {

           i++;
           if(i==1)
               server=item;
           else if(i==3)
               software=item;
           else if(i==4)
               version=item;
           //else
               // i++;

       }    

       cout<<"server  "<<server<<"software  "<<software<<"version   "<<version<<endl;
       multimap<string, innermap >::iterator it;
       it=mp.insert(make_pair(software,innermap()));            
       it->second.insert(make_pair(version,server));

       //print();  
    }
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

I debugged my code, and the values are read in correct from my file before insertion. But when I call `print()`, all but one version are missing:

> MySQL
>   Server1
>  
>   MySQL
>   Server2
>   Python
>   2.6.3  Server3
>   Ubuntu
>   Server2

**Why aren't all version strings printed?**

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: yes before insert version i cheked version value available..

Comment: When stepping through your code with a debugger, one should check all values of variables, at each, and every step of execution, and inspect whether they are the expected values. Did you do that?

Comment: at line 55, version value is present just before insertion.

Comment: @user2279196 : so finally so found your bug ! congratulations

Comment: No.. i not able to find the bug. Please help me to find bug.

Comment: @user2279196 You don't seem to read, what I am writing. If you did all that - you would have found your bug. Since you are actively refusing to do so, that puts me off, from writing further comments..

Comment: When I run your code with the given input, the output is exactly as you expect. You can test it here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/H1Mdzulxm Are you sure your input file is correct and you aren't doing anything else in your code?

Comment: I don't know what i am doing wrong..above online editor giving exact output what i am expecting.Let me check again..

Comment: Maybe tell us what exact compiler you are using, and any possible compiler settings. Are there any warnings or messages from your IDE or compiler that could shed some light?

Comment: @MaxVollmer  Sorry for late reply.. currently i am using cygwin on mintty2.8.4. with gcc version 6.4.0 (GCC).

Comment: Can you confirm that you get the wrong output even with my modified code (from here https://www.onlinegdb.com/H1Mdzulxm)? That would rule out issues with the file.

Comment: Yes its working fine on setup. It means something related to some compiler or cygwin setting, which seems to create issue.